# How to make queue with codeigniter on which a different worker can work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, codeigniter-3

I have worked over Laravel queue creating jobs and its queue automatically takes from the driver specified like database, redis etc. I am currently working on Codeigniter. Just want to know where we can get Queue library and as easy implementation of different worker as in Laravel. A different or background process which can feed on Jobs available on database and then process them.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter doesn't have queue mode,
 But you can use something like [gearman](http://gearman.org/) . CI can use gearman to process a queue.

Or, check this package [here](https://github.com/yidas/codeigniter-queue-worker) . its a really useful codeigniter queue package.